# Fill a new list in R matching columns and rownames

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
mydatamatrix<-matrix(rnorm(30),nrow=10,ncol=26);colnames(mydatamatrix)<-LETTERS[1:26]
pairs<-matrix(LETTERS[1:20],ncol=2);

mylist <- rep(list(vector(mode = "list", 2)),nrow(pairs))
```

I would like to fill my `mylist` list with the column values of `mydatamatrix` matrix but matching with the pairs names.

For example: `mylist[[1]]` should have the values of `A` and `K` columns of `mydatamatrix`.

And `mylist[[1]][1]`should be `A` `mylist[[1]][2]` should be `K`.

How can I do this?

And also I would like to name the positions `mylist[[k]][j]` by the names from `mydatamatrix` columns that will fill `mylist`.

Is it clear?

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the 'pairs' by row and extract the columns of the dataset in a `list`

```
lapply(split(pairs, row(pairs)), function(x) 
        list(mydatamatrix[, x[1]], mydatamatrix[, x[2]]))
```

---

Or assign the already created 'mylist' with the output of extracted values using a `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(mylist)) mylist[[i]] <- list(mydatamatrix[, pairs[i,][1]], 
                       mydatamatrix[, pairs[i, ][2]])
```